# jQuery having trouble showing hidden elements

Tags: jquery

I have some nested lists and was hoping to be able to have a "show all" button at the top, but it doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestions?  I know there are probably other ways of accomplishing similar things, but I was using this as an opportunity to learn more about jquery and was trying to figure out why this particular example wasn't working.

Here is is in action:  http://hortitude.com/samples/jquery_show_trouble.html

And the code....

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $( function () {
          $("h1").click ( function () {
              var subitems = $(".bar");
              $(".bar").show();
          });
          $(".foo").click ( function () {
              var obj = $(this);
              var children = obj.children();
              $(this).children().toggle (500);
          });

      });
    </script>


</head>
<body>
  <h1>show all</h1>
  <ul>
    <li class="foo">item 1
       <ul> 
         <li class="bar">sub-item 1</li>
         <li class="bar">sub-item 2</li>
       </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="foo">item 2
       <ul> 
         <li class="bar">sub-item 1</li>
         <li class="bar">sub-item 2</li>
       </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="foo">item 3
       <ul> 
         <li class="bar">sub-item 1</li>
         <li class="bar">ysub-item 2</li>
       </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are hiding the `<ul>` elements, `$(this).children()` selects the `<ul>` elements inside the particular `.foo` element.
If any ancestor of a visible element is hidden, then the element will still be hidden, thus `$('.foo').show()` has no effect.

Do

```
$(".foo").children().show();
```

---

Btw. a heading element (`<h1>`) is not a button ;) I suggest to use something different.

Comment: I agree <h1> should not be a button, I was just using it within this example

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust your h1 click to do the following:

```
$("h1").click(function() {
    $(".foo").children().show();
});
```

Your `.foo` click is hidding the `ul` list which contains your `.bar` elements.

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/xKcYf/).

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is that this function:

```
      $(".foo").click ( function () {
          var obj = $(this);
          var children = obj.children();
          $(this).children().toggle (500);
      });
```

is hiding the UL items that contain your LI items, so even though you're calling `$(".bar").show()` they're not showing up, because their parent UL items are set to display:none.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("h1").click ( function () {
              var subitems = $(".bar");
              $(".bar").parent().show();
          });
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

thats because you are hiding the ul instead of li when u click a foo :)

`$(this).children().toggle (500);` should be  `$(this).find('li.bar').toggle (500);`